# Case and Count sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to return the value '0' for null results and am having a bit of difficulty. I have tried several combinations, but this is my stored procedure, before accounting for the nulls, as I have gotten nowhere. I need my total to appear as '0' for days there are no appointments for each warehouse. HELP!!!! I'm very stuck.

```
SELECT cis.districtname                                AS [Warehouse], 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cca.appointment_date, 101) AS [Appt Date], 
       COUNT(*)                                        AS [Total] 
FROM   [pscgdassql\dasdb].das_scg.[dbo].[cc.callcenteractivity] cca 
       LEFT JOIN [pscgdassql\dasdb].das_scg.core.WorkOrder wo 
              ON cca.apptheaderworkorder = wo.workorderid 
       LEFT JOIN [pscgdassql\dasdb].das_scg.cis.warehouses cis 
              ON wo.SvtBaseCode = cis.SVCBaseCode 
                 AND wo.Section = cis.section 
WHERE  CAST(cca.appointment_date AS DATE) >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
       AND cca.appointment_date <> '' 
       AND cca.appointment_date IS NOT NULL 
       AND cca.appointment_date <> '01/01/1900' 
       AND wo.WorkOrderStatusInd NOT IN ( 5, 6 ) 
GROUP  BY cis.districtname, 
          CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cca.appointment_date, 101)
```

Comment: Can you show us your current results and what should be returned?  Is the row not returned or does it show null instead of 0?

Comment: Is your problem that the row is not returning? You are filtering out NULL dates (as well as explicitly filtering other values, which does the same thing) in your WHERE clause, so if I'm reading this correctly you won't ever get a row with a '0' for days where there are no appointments. Could you rewrite your WHERE clause to allow the NULL values through?

Comment: I am getting the correct values for the days that have appointments set, but where it should say 'null' or '0', or days that do not have appointments set, I am just getting blanks.